# Laravel middleware sharing variable view does not work when writing HTTP test

Tags: laravel, phpunit, middleware, laravel-testing

We have the following middleware. We know the middleware works since testing the application in browser is working. Sadly when writing HTTP test case, blade is saying that the variable defined by the middleware is not there.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Repository\UserContract;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class Authenticate
{
    private $userRepository;
    private $view;

    public function __construct(UserContract $userRepository, ViewFactory $view)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userId = null;
        $username = null;
        if ($request->hasCookie('auth')) {
            $secret = $request->cookie('auth');
            $userId = $this->userRepository->getUserIdBySecret($secret);
            $username = $this->userRepository->getUsername($userId);
        }
        $this->view->share('username', $username);
        $request['_user_id'] = $userId;
        $request['_username'] = $username;
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

We doing a PHPUnit test as following:

```php
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_shows_logged_in_username()
    {
        $app = $this->createApplication();
        $encrypter = $app->get(Encrypter::class);
        $userRepository = $app->make(UserContract::class);
        $userRepository->addUser('jane', 'secret');

        $secret = $encrypter->encrypt('secret', false);
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/', [], ['auth' => $secret], [], [], null);
        $response->assertSeeText('jane');
    }
```

error

```
ErrorException {#980                                                                                                                                           
  #message: "Undefined variable: username"                                                                                                                     
  #code: 0                                                                                                                                                     
  #file: "./storage/framework/views/db4b9232a3b0957f912084f26d9041e8a510bd6c.php"
  #line: 3                                                                     
  #severity: E_NOTICE                                                          
  trace: {                                                                     
    ./storage/framework/views/db4b9232a3b0957f912084f26d9041e8a510bd6c.php:3 {
      › <?php dump($comments); ?>                                              
      › <?php dump($username); ?>
```

Any advice would be appreciated?

**EDITS**

I have to add that using the `View` facade and called the `share` methods on it make it works but I hit the same issue with the `errors` variable that should be set by the `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` stock laravel middleware.

Other remark, my middleware is called `Authenticate` but it has nothing to do with the normal password based authentication of Laravel.

Here the `UserContract`:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);


namespace App\Repository;


use App\Repository\Exception\UserAlreadyRegisteredException;

interface UserContract
{
    public function isRegistered(string $username): bool;

    public function getUserID(string $username): int;

    public function getUserIdBySecret(string $secret): int;

    /**
     * @param int $userId
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws
     */
    public function getUsername(int $userId): string;

    /**
     * @param int $userId
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws AuthSecretNotSetException
     */
    public function getUserAuthSecret(int $userId): string;

    public function getNextId(): int;

    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $authSecret
     *
     * @return int
     * @throws UserAlreadyRegisteredException
     */
    public function addUser(string $username, string $authSecret): int;

    public function fetchUpdatedBetween(?\DateTimeInterface $start, ?\DateTimeInterface $end): array;

    public function markAsSynced(int $userId): void;

    public function isSynced(int $userId): bool;

    public function delete(int $userId): void;

    public function markAsDeleted(int $userId): void;

    public function fetchDeletedIds(): array;

    public function removeDeletedFlag(int $userId): void;

    public function fetchStalledIds(\DateTimeInterface $dateTime): array;

    public function purge(int $userId): void;

    /**
     * @param UserFetcherContract $fetcher the closure would be passed userId and it should return data or null
     */
    public function setFallbackFetcher(UserFetcherContract $fetcher): void;
}
```

Comment: This might be a silly question but did you try to do a view clear before executing the PHPUnit test?

Comment: I think view is shared service provider, is it possible to share it in middleware?

Comment: Can you share the `UserContract` code? I'd suggest you to double check that the user is being (properly) added in the test.

Comment: @rkg yes, it does not help

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo added `UserContract` to the question

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I think you are onto something but sadly the middleware provided by Laravel seems to use this technique (i.e `ShareErrorsFromSession`). After are they unit tested? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: silly question, but does your test class `use WithoutMiddleware;`?

Comment: can you also share your routes/web.php and app/Http/Kernel.php ?

Comment: It doesn't appear that the route middleware group is loading. Ensure your routing is correct.

Comment: @Erich here the full app https://github.com/RageZBla/ReComment

Comment: @JasonGrim the middleware is loading fine, anyway I found why. My guess about something to do with the container was not far off. More having multiple container in that situation :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally took the time to do a deep dive on this one.

It turns out the issue is happening because I am creating multiple instance of the booted app and somehow it mess with the instance of the view factory registered in the the application.

In the test case removing this line make it works:

```php
/**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_shows_logged_in_username()
    {
        // THIS IS WRONG
        // $app = $this->createApplication();
        $app = $this->app; // Use application instantiated in setUp method of test case
        $encrypter = $app->get(Encrypter::class);
        $userRepository = $app->make(UserContract::class);
        $userRepository->addUser('jane', 'secret');

        $secret = $encrypter->encrypt('secret', false);
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/', [], ['auth' => $secret], [], [], null);
        $response->assertSeeText('jane');
    }
```

I am not 100% sure why booting multiple instance of the app would create issues but my gut feeling is: some shared data somewhere...

For any of you interested here the [commit](https://github.com/RageZBla/ReComment/commit/2b6c6ab253721974efe1b6e5c4e7c1b2fe066509)

Answer (score 2):

#### To properly test logging in you should submit a post request, so change:

```
$response = $this->call('GET', '/', [], ['auth' => $secret], [], [], null);
```

To

```
$response = $this->call('POST', '/', [], ['auth' => $secret], [], [], null);
```

---

#### Alternatively, if you only want to test the view and not the login form itself, you could use the `actingAs` method...

capture the user in a variable when created:

```
$user = $userRepository->addUser('jane', 'secret');
```

use the `actingAs` method to test a view as a logged in `$user`:

```
$this->actingAs($user)->get('/')->assertSeeText('jane');;
```

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned it in the question but we are *not* using the default username/password authentication of Laravel. It's actually custom cookie based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Try `view()->share('username', $username)`

Comment: yes that would fix the problem for my middleware but not the error middleware of laravel...